# how to create schema in doctrine2 orm from windows 7 command prompt

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm

I am following `Doctring` user guide from `doctrine` site. but I faced a problem when I am coming to create `orm` schema. When I run from windows command prompt

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

the console responds with the following error message:

> 'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Please help me.

Comment: have you navigated to the project directory? you could try `./vendor/bin/doctrine`

Comment: I tried it.. it gave me the following error...'**.**' is not recognized

Comment: wow sorry this took so long to spot, use backslashes! I use gitbash on windows so I had forgotten about the different slashes in use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running via windows CMD you need to use backslashes in place of forwardslashes

```
vendor\bin\doctrine
```

As I mentioned in my comment I use [GitBash](https://gitforwindows.org/) for windows (which gives you a bash like environment, meaning you can use forward slashes), I highly recommend it

Comment: I used gitbash and followed your instruction, but it still showing error..here is my code '**/c/xampp/htdocs/doctrine2_tutorial
$ \vendor\bin\doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
bash: vendorbindoctrine: command not found
**'

Comment: If you're using gitbash you use forward sashes